# Find file path and include it

Tags: php, include-path

I have a problem with including a file in all my directory having one or more level depth.

I have directory structure like

```
=>public_html=>first_dir=>index.php
=>public_html=>first_dir=>second_dir=>index.php
=>public_html=>first_dir=>second_dir=>thired_dir=>index.php
```

Now I want to include `config.php` file in all `index.php` those are in different-2 directories having different level of depth. And my `config.php` exist in root folder.

For now I have to place `config.php` file in each folder or have to change include path according to directory depth. Is there any solution that I use one function in each file that automatically find directory depth and include that file automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function to get a path from directory depth

```
function get_include_path($file_name)
{
    $folder_depth = substr_count($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] , "/");
    $directory_level = 1; //If file exist in folder after root use 2
    if($folder_depth == false)
    {
        $folder_depth = 1;
    }
    return str_repeat("../", $folder_depth - $directory_level).$file_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the files using relative path like this for

=>public_html=>first_dir=>index.php => `include("../config.php");`

=>public_html=>first_dir=>second_dir=>index.php => `include("../../config.php");`

=>public_html=>first_dir=>second_dir=>thired_dir=>index.php => `include("../../../config.php");`

OR You can also call in all the files like this

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php';
```

Comment: If I am using subdomain and now my root folder is subdomain folder then $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will for that?

Comment: Then you can use like this  (put a ../ before config.php)   include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../config.php';

Comment: I want to remove efforts to change file path for now I have to change file file path according to directory depth like ../ or ../../ DOCUMENT_ROOT is solution if I am using main domain. Is there same solution for subdomain?

Comment: I think above code include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../config.php'; should work.